# C Lang: Check if palindrome using pointers and arrays

Tags: c, pointers

I been trying to code this with pointers I was able to get the first for loop to work but I can't get the other for loop to work using pointers.The program will ignore all characters that aren’t letters and use pointers to instead of integers to keep track of positions in the array. I need help with the pointers  to keep track of position in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 50

int main()
{   
    int i, j, k =0,*count;    char ch, msg[N], msg1[N];    bool flag = true;
    char *p;



    count = &k;
    // Getting user-defined input   
    printf("Enter a massage: ");
    ch = getchar();   
    while(ch != '\n' || *count == N) 
    { 

      msg[(*count)++] = ch;
      ch = getchar();   
    } // end of while loop

    // Printing user-defined input   
    printf("User-defined input: ");   
    for(p = msg; p < msg+*count; p++)       
      printf("%c",  *p);   

    printf("\nNumber of characters is %d\n", *count);       

    // Sanitiazation of the msg array (i.e., removing special characters)   
     i = 0;   
    for(j = 0; msg[j]; j++) {       
       if(isalpha(msg[j]))           
              msg1[i++] = tolower(msg[j]);   
    } // end of for loop        

   // Palindrome test    
   for(j = 0; msg1[j]; j++) {       
      if(msg1[j] != msg1[i-j-1]) {           
      flag = false;           
      continue;       
      }   
    } // end of for loop       

   // Printing final decision   
   if(flag)         
      printf("Palindrome\n");   
   else       
      printf("Not palindrome\n");    

   return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: `count = &k;` Why do you need code like this? Why not just use `k` directly as there doesn't seem to be any reason for the pointer.

Comment: This looks overly complicated. Moreover, there's no point in using `continue;` as the last statement of a loop.

Comment: @kaylum I am supposed to be using pointers instead of using integer to keep track of the position of  array.

Comment: @babon  I agree with you, but my Professor wants us to modify his code by using pointers instead. I managed to do the first for loop, but I cant figure out how to do the rest of the code with pointers

Comment: There's using pointers and there is using pointers. What you have doesn't make sense and I doubt your professor wants you to do that. My guess is that the intention is for you to use pointers not for the index but directly pointing into the arrays to track the positions.